# How to generate correlated binary variables

Tags: algorithm, math, random, statistics, probability

I need to generate a series of *N* random binary variables with a given correlation function. Let *x* = {*x*<sub>*i*</sub>} be a series of binary variables (taking the value 0 or 1, *i* running from 1 to *N*). The marginal probability is given Pr(*x*<sub>*i*</sub> = 1) = *p*, and the variables should be correlated in the following way:

*Corr*[ *x*<sub>*i*</sub> *x*<sub>*j*</sub> ] = const × |*i*−*j*|<sup>−α</sup> (for i!=j)

where α is a positive number.

If it is easier, consider the correlation function:

*Corr*[ *x*<sub>*i*</sub> *x*<sub>*j*</sub> ] = (|*i*−*j*|+1)<sup>−α</sup>

The essential part is that I want to investigate the behavior when the correlation function goes like a power law. (not α<sup>|*i*−*j*|</sup> )

Is it possible to generate a series like this, preferably in Python?

Comment: @Paul: No, definitely not: *“MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer research level math questions, the sorts of questions you come across when you're writing or reading articles or graduate level books.”* Pretty much all SO math-related questions *don't* fall under this.

Comment: @johannes: OK - thanks for the clarification - it seems like more of a maths question than a programming question in that the programming will be trivial once the maths is nailed down, but it sounds like there is nowhere more suitable to ask this kind of question.

Comment: Is it correct to interpret the correlation as roughly "the bigger the difference of the indices of two variables is, the smaller is the probability of both being 1"?  Intuitively, this prefers clusters.

Comment: @Svante: said in another way: the bigger the difference of the indices of the variables, the more they behave as independent variables. Your intuition is right, this prefers clusters.

Comment: I don't think this is possible as written. When N is very large, the expected product of widely separated xi must be very close to zero, and we can find a set of 1/p + 1 that must essentially be mutually exclusive despite all having probability p. Perhaps you meant E[xi xj] - p^2 = ... ?

Comment: Also, what range of N are you thinking about, and would you accept a different decay function (say exponential, since it would be a lot easier)?

Comment: @algorithmist: your rigth Corr[xi xj] = E[xi xj] - p^2, I hope to have an N in the order of 1000-10000.

Comment: This setup seems to have a lot in common with the binary Ising model, although it would take effort to work out exactly what your assumed correlation structure implies.  Because every item is connected, I doubt there is a one-shot simulation strategy.  You most likely want to implement a Gibbs sampler. Work out the conditional distribution of any particular element, holding the others fixed, and then iteratively simulate from that, starting from a random position.

Comment: jonalm: are you sure it's |i-j|^-alpha rather than alpha^|i-j| ? (just checking for obvious typos)

Comment: @jonalm: Could you edit your question with the correct correlation formula ? It's easier to look up in the function.

Comment: jonalm, do you need to implement this specific correlation structure, or just some correlation structure the stength of which decreases with distance (and is modifiable by one parameter)?

Comment: @Jason S, @Aniko and @Matthhiu M. the essential feature of the correlation function is the power law. I have edited the question. hope it is clear.

@Tristan, that is right, this is essentially the Ising model at the critical point. Thanks for the imput.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for all your inputs. I found an answer to my question in the cute little article by Chul Gyu Park et al., so in case anyone run into the same problem, look up:

"A simple method for Generating Correlated Binary Variates" (jstor.org.stable/2684925)

for a simple algorithm. The algorithm works if all the elements in the correlation matrix are positive, and for a general marginal distribution Pr(x_i)=p_i.

j

Comment: interesting... see also http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.imsc/1233152938&page=record

Comment: Did you implement this in Python? Do you still have the script? Any chance you could include it please?

Comment: @JasonS That link is dead.

Comment: I don't even remember what that was, but it's available in archive.org https://web.archive.org/web/20160922011407/http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.imsc/1233152938&page=record

Answer (score 2):

You're describing a random *process*, and it looks like a tough one to me... if you eliminated the binary (0,1) requirement, and instead specified the expected value and variance, it would be possible to describe this as a white noise generator feeding through a 1-pole low-pass filter, which I think would give you the α<sup>|i-j|</sup> characteristic.

This actually might meet the bar for mathoverflow.net, depending on how it is phrased. Let me try asking....

---

update: I did [ask on mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18268/discrete-stochastic-process-exponentially-correlated-bernoulli) for the α<sup>|i-j|</sup> case. But perhaps there are some ideas there that can be adapted to your case.

Comment: It's actually |i-j|^-\alpha; the solution for \alpha^|i-j| is in the literature.

Comment: hmmm... |i-j|^-alpha has no solution for i=j. Are we sure the OP did not mis-state?

Comment: It can be Corr[xi xj] = const x|i-j|^-alpha for i != j, or Corr[xj xi] = (|i-j|+1)^alfa (whatever is easiest). Either way, Im not claiming that they are equal, but only interested in the tail behavior (|i-j| >> 1) so it should not matter.

Comment: Thank you so much Jason. Although it was a different correlation, the solutions were really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search at [**RSeek**](http://www.rseek.org) reveals that [**R**](http://www.r-project.org) has packages

- [**bindata**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=bindata)
- [**binarySimCLF**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=binarySimCLF)

to do this.

Comment: That was my first idea too, but I doubt they could handle N=1000-10000 per jonalm's statement in the comments.

Comment: I dont know R, but this seems like a reason to learn it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Express the distribution *x<sub>i</sub>* as a linear combination of some independent basis distributions *f<sub>j</sub>*: *x<sub>i</sub> = a<sub>i1</sub>f<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>i2</sub>f<sub>2</sub> + ...* . Let us constrain *f<sub>j</sub>* to be independent variables uniformly distributed in 0..1 or in {0,1} (discrete). Let us now express everything we know in matrix form:

```
Let X be the vector (x1, x2, .., xn)
Let A be the matrix (a_ij) of dimension (k,n) (n rows, k columns)
Let F be the vector (f1, f2, .., fk) 
Let P be the vector (p1, p2, .., pn)
Let R be the matrix (E[x_i,x_j]) for i,j=1..n
Definition of the X distribution: X = A * F
Constraint on the mean of individual X variables: P = A * (1 ..k times.. 1)
Correlation constraint: AT*A = 3R or 2R in the discrete case (because E[x_i x_j] = 
  E[(a_i1*f_1 + a_i2*f_2 + ...)*(a_j1*f_1 + a_j2*f_2 + ...)] =
  E[sum over p,q: a_ip*f_p*a_jq*f_q] = (since for p/=q holds E[f_p*f_q]=0)
  E[sum over p: a_ip*a_jp*f_p^2] =
  sum over p: a_ip*a_jp*E[f_p^2] = (since E[f_p^2] = 1/3 or 1/2 for the discrete case)
  sum over p: 1/3 or 1/2*a_ip*a_jp
And the vector consisting of those sums over p: a_ip*a_jp is precisely AT*A.
```

Now you need to solve the two equations:

```
AT*A      = 3R (or 2R in the discrete case)
A*(1...1) = P
```

Solution of the first equation corresponds to finding the square root of the matrix 3R or 2R. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_factorization and generally http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix .
Something also should be done about the second one :)

I ask mathematicians around to correct me, because I may very well have mixed AT*A with A*AT or done something even more wrong.

To generate a value of *x<sub>i</sub>* as a linear mixture of the basis distributions, use a two-step process: 1) use a uniform random variable to choose one of the basis distributions, weighted with corresponding probability, 2) generate a result using the chosen basis distribution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the continuous -> discrete transition is often the hardest part. For example, the problem of finding a Hadamard matrix gets a _lot_ easier if complex entries are allowed. I don't see any way to discretize your solution within the given framework.

Comment: Why should it be hard? The solution just depends on the resulting distribution being a linear mixture of basis distributions but I don't see how it depends on their continuity. Is it that discrete distributions can't easily be linearly mixed?

Comment: In this case it's the fact that your continuous distributions aren't convex combinations of Bernoulli trials.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. I know what is a convex combination and what are Bernoulli trials, but still: I've edited my post; does not the process described in the last paragraph give a correct result? If so, could you point me to some sources expanding your point? (anyways, probably I should just implement the stuff I described and see if it works)

Comment: The problem is that A may have entries that are not between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

The brute force solution is to express the constraints of the problem as a linear program with `2^N` variables `pr(w)` where `w` ranges over all binary strings of length `N`. First the constraint that `pr` be a probability distribution:

```
for all w: 0 <= pr(w) <= 1
sum_w pr(w) = 1
```

Second, the constraint that the expectation of each variable be `p`:

```
for all i: sum_{w such that w[i] = 1} pr(w) = p
```

Third, the covariance constraints:

```
for all i < j: sum_{w such that w[i] = w[j] = 1} pr(w) = const * |j - i|^alpha - p^2
```

This is very slow, but a cursory literature search turned up nothing better. If you decide to implement it, here are some LP solvers with Python bindings: http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Libraries

Comment: I don't know linear programming, but I do not see how this will work. Any configuration of the binary series will have a non-zero probability. Is it possible to calculate the probability of any configuration?

Comment: Yes, if the problem is solvable, then the LP routine will give you the probability of each of the 2^N configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an intuitive / experimental approach that seems to work.

If **b** is an binary r.v.,
**m** is the mean of the binary r.v., 
**c** is the correlation you want,
**rand()** generates a U(0,1) r.v., and 
**d** is the correlated binary r.v. you want:

d = if(rand() < c, b, if(rand() < m , 0, 1))

That is if a uniform r.v. is less than the desired correlation, d = b.  Otherwise d = another random binary number.

I ran this 1000 times for a column of 2000 binary r.v.s. with m=.5 and c = .4 and c = .5
The correlation mean was exactly as specified, the distribution appeared to be normal. 
For a correlation of 0.4 the std deviation of the correlation was 0.02.

Sorry - I can't prove that this works all the time, but you have to admit, it sure is easy.

Comment: Reread the question: that's not the right correlation structure.